# how to make jar file from commandline in ubuntu

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am kinda stuck. Usually I use the export option in eclipse to create a jar.
But now, i have deployed my code in production and want to create a jar file.

So I have two files,

```
 foo.java which calls bar.java
```

And then it uses couple of jars

```
foobar.jar foo_bar.jar
```

Now,so main is in foo.java

How do i create an executable jar.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

Here's a great article on the topic: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/jar.kaffe.1.html

Basically:

```
 $jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class
```

Comment: Check out the command flags in the sourced link. Your answer is in there.